# How would I store an item in a list from a function activated by an onkeypress call

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

trying to create a program that takes keyboard input and stores it in a list for later use in anylisation.

```
import turtle as trtl
from functools import partial

wn = trtl.Screen()

def _onkeypress(self, fun, key=None):
    if fun is None:
        if key is None:
            self.cv.unbind("<KeyPress>", None)
        else:
            self.cv.unbind("<KeyPress-%s>" % key, None)
    elif key is None:
        def eventfun(event):
            fun(event.char)
        self.cv.bind("<KeyPress>", eventfun)
    else:
        def eventfun(event):
            fun()
        self.cv.bind("<KeyPress-%s>" % key, eventfun)

def letter(character):
    phL = character
    print(phL)

def makeL(self):
  L = []
  phL = wn.onkeypress(letter)
  L.append(phL)
  print(L)

wn._onkeypress = partial(_onkeypress, wn)
wn.onkeypress(letter)
wn.onkeypress(makeL)
wn.listen()
wn.mainloop()
```

The value I get in the console for the print L is just `[]`. I have no idea why this is happening. But `phL` in the function letter prints and updates, while the list stays empty.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you're doing:

```
phL = wn.onkeypress(letter)
```

indicates that you don't have a basic understanding of turtle events.  The `onkeypress()` function doesn't stop execution and wait for a key to be pressed, it simply registers a function to be called if/when a key is pressed.  I.e. it doesn't return anything.  To make things work the way I think you desire:

```
from turtle import Screen
from functools import partial

def _onkeypress(self, fun, key=None):
    if fun is None:
        if key is None:
            self.cv.unbind("<KeyPress>", None)
        else:
            self.cv.unbind("<KeyPress-%s>" % key, None)
    elif key is None:
        def eventfun(event):
            fun(event.char)
        self.cv.bind("<KeyPress>", eventfun)
    else:
        def eventfun(event):
            fun()
        self.cv.bind("<KeyPress-%s>" % key, eventfun)

def letter(character):
    characters.append(character)
    print(characters)

screen = Screen()
screen._onkeypress = partial(_onkeypress, screen)  # monkey patch

characters = []

screen.onkeypress(letter)
screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

As you type at the turtle window, the increasing list `characters` will print to the console.

N.B. `_onkeypress` is a slight modification of turtle's own `onkeypress` method that allows the key typed to be passed through to the event handler in the "any key" case.  A failing in the original which passes nothing.